# Using a custom view from xml. View class cast error

Tags: android, exception, custom-view, android-custom-view

When running my code i get a java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View when I initialise the XML layout for my view.

Why?

**UPDATE**

Problem was since I was adding a button inside a view element. Corrected this placement and it worked again

Comment: The exception was caused by the call to `setContentView` at SearchWindow.java line 49 (in `onCreate()`). Perhaps you should post that code and associated XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem was elsewhere. Was adding a button inside a view element which seemed to be cause the exception.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since we see that it can't cast to `android.view.View` I can only guess that `AppZappy.NIRailAndBus.UI.ToggleImageButton` does not extend View or a subclass of View but I would need to see the class declaration to verify that.

Comment: It extends ImageButton. Which extends View. I've added the class code